# How to limit value (based on sum of similar items)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a action tracker/to-do list and I want to assign points to each action item. I want to allow the user to add as many items as they'd like, but have a limit on the sum of "totalpts" for all action items to be 1000. How can I do this?

As a matter of reference, here is a partial of my display code:

```
<% @todo_list.todo_items.order('totalpts DESC').each do |todo_item| %>
  <% if todo_item.completed? && todo_item.created_at.strftime("%U").to_i == Date.today.strftime("%U").to_i %>
  <tr id="<%= dom_id(todo_item) %>">
    <td><%= todo_item.completed_at.strftime("%A ") %></td>
    <td><%= todo_item.content %></td>
    <td><%= todo_item.currentpts %></td>
    <td><%= todo_item.totalpts %></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the `min` function from the `Enum` class.

```
[1, 3].min
=> 1
```

Something along the lines of this is what you should be looking for.

```
[1000, calculate_points_for_action(action)].min
```

This should return the lower number between the two. In this case, `1000` is the max number of points you can have for a given action.

I would also consider putting the `1000` into a constant. This would allow you to easily change it in the future by only requiring a change in a single location instead of having to find all invocations.

Comment: How would I do this in the controller? I'm assuming that's where I should place it. I understand what you're recommending but struggling to understand how to implement.

Comment: This would actually be better suited in the model if you are using MVC. This is because it is just manipulating data, which is what the model should be doing. This way, if you put it into a model function called `points_for_action(action)`, you could just do `myObject.points_for_action(action)`. Assuming you are doing different calculations for different actions.